# Unity-How do I keep Primitive Objects from Overlapping?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I made a test game for whenever I push a button, it create a class object from a factory class. I want to make it so everytime I spawn an object, it keeps from overlapping other objects. Also, I want to keep the sphere and light object together everytime I spawn. Can you help me figure out how to do that?

```
public class Sphere : Shape
{

    public Sphere()
    {
        float speed = 10f;

        GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
        sphere.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        sphere.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Random.ColorHSV();
        sphere.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        Destroy(sphere, 30.0f);

        GameObject lightGameObject = new GameObject("Light");
        Light lightComp = lightGameObject.AddComponent<Light>();
        lightComp.color = Random.ColorHSV();
        lightGameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        lightGameObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        Destroy(lightComp, 30.0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a prefab with the light attached to the sphere, then spawn that prefab. Record the positions, get a position that's not recorded yet...spawn there.

Comment: I don't want to create a prefab. I want to create primitve.

Comment: and - if i may ask - why dont you want to do it "the way its done"?

Comment: Because there is more than one way to do it, and I want a way that translates well into my code without changing the whole thing.

Comment: Might wanna tell us what's the problem with your current approach ... you spawn a sphere and a light together... where is your problem?

Comment: I'm going to put that aside for now and ask how do I keep primitive spheres I create from overlapping.

Comment: I told you in my first comment.You should show us what you tried, then we can answer... this is not "we do the coding for your".

Comment: @KennethDionisi if you need to change your whole code to make use of a prefab instead of what you do atm, your codebase could do with a complete doover anyways. but this aside, to fix your problem with overlapping spheres, how you best archieve that is a matter of your requirements. you could spawn them on a grid (fe. triangles in 2d or tetraeder in 3d) that packs nicely or if you want it more random you should look into flocking behaviours.